# C library linked to Ox

Tags: c, state-space, interactive-brokers, ox

I'm currently playing around with state space models and [the book I'm using](http://listinet.com/bibliografia-comuna/Cdu339-C8E1.pdf) has some very useful examples.

**Problem:**

These examples are written in Ox, which somewhat limits its usability, particularly as I want to test out some of my models using the Interactive Brokers API, for which it's more practical to use C# / C++.

More specifically it's using examples from `SsfPack` which according to [this article](http://file://affinityshipping.local/ldn/Users/georgenordahl/Downloads/v41i03.pdf) is "a library of routines for state space
modelling and inference written in C and linked to Ox".

Does this mean it can be directly implemented in C or is it a better approach to write the function in Ox and then call it in C as shown in A1.4 of [this document](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/system/man/ox-3.20/OxAppendix.pdf)? And if it can be directly implemented, how does one go about it?

Having some experience with C and no experience with Ox, the former of these two options would be much preferable.

Any thoughts welcome!

Comment: Is there any reason you added the C++ tag for a C question? Are your sure you use C, not C++? They are **different** languages, pick the one you actually use!

Comment: Hi @Olaf, the reason I added C++ was for the same reason that I mentioned it in the question, namely its usage in the interactive brokers API, which I hope to incorporate these models in. I do appreciate that they are different languages, but if memory serves me (might be wrong here I which case I apologise), there is a great deal of compatibility between the various variation of the C languages.

Comment: There are no "C language**s**". There is only **one** C language standardised as ISO 9899:2011. To repeat: C++ is a different language. Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics. If you compile with a C++ compiler, this is C++, **not C**.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the clarification, I'll edit the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no official documentation for Ssfpack C routines. Conversely, the ssfpack Ox documentation is well detailed ( see '*SsfPack 3.0: Statistical Algorithms for Models in State Space Form*' by Koopman and Doornik ).

If you are an experienced C developer you can observe the ox header file ssfpack.h, you'll find some "`extern`" declared functions that refers to dll located functions. Those functions can be used in C but you need to find by yourself the prototype of the function. This can be really tricky, maybe impossible, for functions where the number of arguments is not known/not constant.

So, you can call Ssfpack directly from C but, due to the lack of documentation, it is very difficult.

For this reason I would recommend that you write your code in Ox and then call it from C or C#. This require that you learn OX, a good starting point is the book *Introduction to Ox* by Doornik and Ooms (2006). Then, you need to read the *Developer's manual for Ox 7* by Doornik (2012) to understand how to call Ox from C.